# Online auto complete auto suggest service

Tags: web-services, autocomplete

Is there any paid online service which will provide support for auto suggest and auto complete. Basically i have a huge set of auto complete data and instead of me maintaining the data , i would like some online provider to maintain this data and server to users on request.

Is there any vendor providing this service ?

Comment: I think there are Place autocomplete, and geo location web-services, though I am not sure if any specific paid online service provider which also provide auto suggest and auto complete for custom data. You can probably use Google App Engine or Google storage (https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/storage-overview) and do minimal implementation on it, there are some examples on the link.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is a service that indexes your raw data into autocomplete then you could make use of hosted ElasticSearch services like [qbox.io](https://qbox.io/), [searchify.com](https://www.searchify.com/), [Found.no](https://www.found.no/) and [more](http://www.slant.co/topics/170/~what-are-the-best-hosted-elasticsearch-services)

You need to index your data first into the elastic search and then query for auto-completion. A detailed explanation on how to achieve that is explained in this [rackspace blog](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/qbox/) and [searchify](https://www.searchify.com/documentation/tutorial-autocomplete).

Excerpt from the rackspace developer blog:

> Auto-complete (e.g. the slick functionality you see when you begin
>   typing in the search box at the top of your Facebook feed) is an
>   extremely popular feature in applications these days. While a wildcard
>   query in a typical data store like MySQL or MongoDB performs
>   adequately with thousands of records, producing near-instant response
>   times with millions or even billions of records would be a joke.
>   ElasticSearch is a powerful tool for large datasets needing full-text
>   queries.